# Indexing in ESE

Tags: windows, database, storage, low-level

Does the Microsoft "Extensible Storage Engine" expose enough access to the storage manager to allow me to write a custom access method, for example a [GiST](http://gist.cs.berkeley.edu/)?

Alternatively, is there a basic log manager / buffer pool manager project for Windows that I could extend to play around with GiST without re-inventing the entire wheel? (Access methods are the part I am interested in experimenting with, so I don't mind re-inventing that.)

Comment: It's funny - none of the top Google searches for 'Microsoft Extensible Search Engine ESE' make any mention of why it is 'extensible'.

Comment: Yeah, no kidding. I think they meant something more like 'reusable'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ESE does not allow you to create a custom access method. It is a very no-frills database engine.